# PKCS 11 returns a wrong token info for my chip cards

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11

I have two smart card readers connected to my computer and each has a card plugged in. Using the PKCS 11 API I want to find out if the user PIN of the smarts cards is locked. According to the API [documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html) we must retrieve an object of the struct `CK_TOKEN_INFO` which contains the `flags` field. There, the bit flag `CKF_SO_PIN_LOCKED` is set if the PIN is locked.

My problem is that the `flags` field does not change if I have a locked smart card and an unlocked one. I know that one of my two chip cards has a locked user PIN. I entered a wrong PIN 6 times and a program that we use to write on the smart cards tells me that the PIN is indeed locked. However the `flags` field is the same for both cards.

Here is a minimal program which demonstrates the issue:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include "cm-pkcs11.h"

  unsigned long slotCount = 0ul;
  CK_RV result;

  std::vector<CK_SLOT_ID> vecSlotIds;

  int main() {

    result = C_Initialize(nullptr);

    result = C_GetSlotList(CK_TRUE, nullptr, &slotCount);

    std::cout << "Found " << slotCount << " slots" << std::endl;

    vecSlotIds.resize(slotCount);
    result = C_GetSlotList(CK_TRUE, vecSlotIds.data(), &slotCount);

    for (const auto& id : vecSlotIds) {
      CK_TOKEN_INFO tokenInfo = {};
      result = C_GetTokenInfo(id, &tokenInfo);
      std::cout << "id: " << id << ", flags: " << tokenInfo.flags << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

The output is:

`Found 2 slots
id: 1, flags: 1037
id: 2, flags: 1037`

As you can see, both `flags` are identical. Do I use the API incorrect here?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem in your code so it might be a bug in the implementation of PKCS#11 library you are using. If you want to check with other tool written in other language you can try [Pkcs11Admin](https://pkcs11admin.net).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the tool jariq mentioned in his comment and it seems the API implementation that we use has indeed a bug. You can see it in the image below. It says for both cards that they are not locked. But one of them is locked.
Thank you jariq.

[image: The tool uses our pkcs11.so and shows also that the card is not locked. But it is locked.]